# is it ok to have a try/catch in a finally?

Tags: c#

is that an "ok" code?

```
        try
        { /*stuff*/ }
        catch (Exception e)
        { /*stuff*/ }
        finally
        {
            try
            { /*stuff*/ }
            catch { /*empty*/ }
        }
```

I need to do complex operation in the finally and it might crash since it's connecting to the a DB

this look weird to me, so. is this the proper way?

Comment: Is it okay to take pills if you have a medical condition? Let's fill in the blanks here. There's nothing wrong with the concept of try/catch inside a finally, but there could be things wrong depending on what you're trying to do, and what your end goals are.

Comment: could you breifly tell us what you are going to do in the finally?

Comment: Depends on what the exception is and how you intend to handle it.  At minimum I would abstract the body of the finally down to a single line.

Comment: Looks like a bit of a code smell to me...
Maybe the code in your `finally` block belongs in another function.

Comment: In one sentence - Yikes yowsers and sheesh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really going to depend on what you are doing, but personally, if it is truly after the other try catch and done after the operation I wouldn't nest it in a finally, just treat it as another try catch.  That would remove some of the "oddity" in it.

Comment: this make me look again at the whole picture(code) and in fact your right, in my case, it's better to remove the finally and add another try/catch after the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Nested try/catch blocks are not ideal, but in certain cases it's necessary. Just make sure to handle any errors correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Idomatically, you would do this:

```
try
{
    /* stuff */
}
catch 
{
    /* stuff */
}
finally 
{
    DoStuff();
}


void DoStuff()
{
    try 
    {
        /* stuff */
    }
    catch
    {
        /* stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense, I don't see how it solves a problem, and is hardly an ideal situation.  I would argue both try catch statements should be in their own method, called within a method, one after another.  These methods should return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An exception in `finally` will **hide** the original exception. This is similar to the recommendation `not to use using in WCF while creating proxies` - although that itself is a different discussion.

This will output B rather than A:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("A");
            }
            finally
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("B");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Usually throwing an exception while another exception is active will result in the first exception getting replaced by the second (later) exception.

Here is some code that illustrates what happens:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("first exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                //try
                {
                    throw new Exception("second exception");
                }
                //catch (Exception)
                {
                    //throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

- Run the code and you will see "second exception"
- Uncomment the try and catch statements and you will see "first exception"
- Also uncomment the throw; statement and you will see "second exception" again.